# React Private Routing Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, react-router

I want to add private route in my react app that when a user login will redirect to account page I use firebase as my database.

I saw some tutorial but I think that's code is for mern stack like that. Could you help me how I will implement the private route this is my code thanks.

**Sign Up**

```
class SignUp extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();

this.state = {
  displayName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  confirmPassword: "",
};
}

handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;

if (password !== confirmPassword) {
  alert("Password don't match");
  return;
}

try {
  const { user } = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email,
    password
  );

  await createUserProfileDocument(user, { displayName });

  this.setState({
    displayName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
};

handleChange = (event) => {
const { name, value } = event.target;

this.setState({ [name]: value });
};

 render() {
const { displayName, email, password, confirmPassword } = this.state;
return (
  <div className="sign-up">
    {Form}
  </div>
);
}
}

export default SignUp;
```

**Sign In**

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  email: "",
  password: "",
};
}

handleSubmit = async (event) => {
event.preventDefault();

const { email, password } = this.state 

try {
  await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  this.setState({ email: "", password: "" });
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  
}


};

handleChange = (event) => {
const { value, name } = event.target;

this.setState({ [name]: value });
};

render() {
return (
  <div className="sign-in">
    {form}
  </div>
);
}
}

export default SignIn;
```

**App js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor() {
super();

this.state = {
  currentUser: null,
};
}

unsubscribeFromAuth = null;

componentDidMount() {
this.unsubscribeFromAuth = 
auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
  if (userAuth) {
    const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);

    userRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
      this.setState({
        currentUser: {
          id: snapShot.id,
          ...snapShot.data(),
        },
      });
    });
    
  } else {
    this.setState({currentUser: userAuth})
  }
});
}

componentWillUnmount() {
this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
}

render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Header currentUser={this.state.currentUser} />
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
      <Route path="/shop" component={ShopPAge} />
      <Route path="/signin" component={SignInAndSignUpPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options

First, at component itself use `this.props.history.push` after wrapping component with `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
...
try {
  await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  this.setState({ email: "", password: "" });
  this.props.history.push('/shop') // in case you want redirect to shop
}

...

export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

Second, use `render` instead `component` at the route declaration, and use `Redirect` component

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

...

<Route path="/signin" render={()=>this.state.currentUser ? <Redirect to='/shop' /> :<SignInAndSignUpPage/>} />
```

Comment: I noticed that if signin with google it's not redirect to shop